# Is any part of my grails app run on grails clean

Tags: grails, execute

I love how grails has environment dependent checking available so I can run certain things in the BootStrap only when testing (`Environment.current == Environment.TEST`).  I have written some groovy code I want to run every time I test, and it's working great!!

Now I want some groovy code to run every time I do `grails clean`.  Is there anywhere in the grails project that is run on clean where I can slip some codes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `scripts/_Events.groovy` if it doesn't exist and add the code in a handler for the "CleanStart" event:

```
eventCleanStart = { kind ->
   // do work here
}
```

p.s. that's `Environment.TEST`